# Issue with evaluating one array, but writing the value to another

Tags: c, arrays

I have a simple game project i'm working on to learn/improve my C knowledge. At the moment i have an array that contains a 'map' of my terrain, it also contains items and enemies. This is working fine, but to improve it, i'm trying to have two arrays that overlap, so i never put item's on the terrain, but in a separate item array which overlaps the terrain. 
I've approached it in the way below;

```
void items(int * terrainMap, int itemCount, int * itemMap){
    int newx = getRand(0, xsize);
    int newy = getRand(0, ysize);
    int count = 0;
    while (count < itemCount){
        if (getCell(newx, newy, terrainMap) == corridoor|| getCell(newx, newy, terrainMap) == floor){
            setCell(newx, newy, chest, itemMap);
            count++;
        }
        else {
            newx = getRand(0, xsize);
            newy = getRand(0, ysize);
        }
    }
}
```

Both arrays are initialized, terrain is mapped out, items is set to empty tiles. What i'm trying to do is in the if conditions, check if the terrain is passable (corridor or floor) and if so, place a chest- but place it in the item array, not on the terrain. The above code work if i place a chest on terrain, but only ever seems to place one chest in the item array.

Can someone please over me some assistance as to where i'm going wrong? Or suggest some improvements to this method? Thanks very much in advance - i'm very new to C and coding so any advice is great.

Comment: Have you used a step-through debugger?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't modify `newx` and `newy` after adding the chest (you aren't hitting the else), so you end up adding the chest to the same position `itemCount` times.

You can fix this by moving your assignment of `newx` and `newy` outside of the else (to update them every time you enter the loop). You might also want to check if there isn't already a chest at that position to guarantee you get that many chests.

Comment: That's brilliant, i actually can't believe i didn't spot that. Thanks very much. I think i need to do some reading on how to use the debugger...